# Retrieving Private Array Data in Handlebars.js Template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, information-hiding

Given this plain JavaScript construct:

```
var MyObject = function() {
  var privateArray = [
    { name: 'one' },
    { name: 'two' }
  ];
  this.returnPrivate = function(index) {
    return privateArray[index];  
  };
};
var obj = new MyObject();
```

Within a handlebars template I would like to be able to print the `name` property of an object at a particular index of the `privateArray` using the `returnPrivate` function.

```
// This of course does not work.
<p>{{returnPrivate(1).name}}</p>
```

I am just starting out with handlebars.js, so there might already be a standard way of doing this.  Or this might be trying to build too much logic into the template and be going against what handlebars is all about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a Helper that does what I need it to, but I would very much appreciate some feedback as to whether this is the best way to solve this type of problem with Handlebars.

```
/**
 * Given the name of a function that returns an array value, this helper
 * returns the value at a given index.  Optionally it takes a property name
 * in case the array value at the given index is itself an object.
 */
Handlebars.registerHelper('eqf', function(func, index, prop) {
  if (typeof prop === 'string') {
    return func(index)[prop];
  } else {
    return func(index);
  }
});
```

Usage for question example:

```
<p>{{eqf returnPrivate 1 "name"}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars has a special syntax for dealing with numeric or symbol identifiers, [as described here](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html).  If you are able to pass the array index as a literal, you can use the following:

```
{{privateArray.[1].name}}
```

That only works if you restructure the object to make `privateArray` available to the template.  If you really want to hide `privateArray` and force the template to use a function call, then you must use a helper.